# Fab button on the center of CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to create a layout for the `CardView` similar to the image below, the problem is that I do not know where to put the `FAB` in my layout, I tried with the `LinearLayout` but not " overlap" the `CardView`, or is in or out, I need some advice

[image]

Here's what I tried (only an example)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <!-- Other object -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case FAB needs to sit outside of CardView. Wrap CardView inside Frame layout.

```
<FrameLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     // put content of card here
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<Fab />
<FrameLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work , the FAB is still positioned outside the card (or inside) and not the limit

Comment: Of course, you have to position it at proper position! I just gave you base where to start. Experiment with aligment of fab, mayby add some padding bottom to CardView

Comment: Thanks , I'm trying to set the padding programmatically but that gets too variable in the different card layout